# How to show a specific <div> for a specific product?

Tags: php, html, yii

I have setup a small webstore and I want to show this `<div class ="data-plan"></div>` only for one single product. My database table from where I want to match this id is called `sb_files` and it has these fields `id` `table_id` `path` `type` `slide_link`, so I am trying to get my code to go trough that table, search up the id ( Its 13040100 ) and if it matches then to show the div, else it shows an empty div. I am using the Yii2 framework, which is php based. So far I have tried this

```
<?php if($product->$this->id('13040100')): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $index = 1;
            foreach($product->() as $prd):
                if(strpos($prd->getPath(), '13040100') == true) {
                    ?>
                                   <div class="wrap">
<div class="data-plan" style="height:20px; width:65px; background-color:#00a651; float:right;color:white;margin:10px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">A+++</a> </div>
<div class="data-plan" style="height:20px; width:65px; background-color:#ed1c1c; float:right;color:white;margin:10px;"><a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">Datu lapa</a> </div>
</div>
                    <?php
                    $index++;
                }
        
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
 <div class="wrap">

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Yii2 framework myself, but are you sure that `$product->$this->id('13040100')` is correct? It looks weird to me, shouldn't it be something like `$product->id('13040100')`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was way easier than I tought, just had to think simple

```
       <?php if ($product->id == '13001100'): ?>
                    <div class="wrap">
                      <div class="data-plan" style="height:20px; width:65px; background-color:#00a651; float:right;color:white;margin:10px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">A+++</a> </div>"
                             <div class="data-plan" style="height:20px; width:65px; background-color:#ed1c1c; float:right;color:white;margin:10px;"><a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">Datu lapa</a> </div>
                             </div>
        <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="wrap">
                    </div>
                <?php endif;
```